# Either another instance of LibreOffice is accessing your personal settings or your personal settings are locked

Tags: libreoffice

Every time I try to open a word document in LibreOffice 3.5, I get this error:

> Either another instance of LibreOffice is accessing your personal settings or your personal settings are locked. Simultaneous access can lead to inconsistencies in your personal settings. Before continuing, you should make sure user ___ closes LibreOffice on host ___.

I've searched various forums in search of a remedy, but haven't found a solution.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: For the record, if someone with a Mac has this problem, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113189/libreoffice-error-either-another-instance-of-libreoffice-is-accessing-your-per for the (slightly different) correct file to find.

Answer (score 13):

If you're absolutely sure libreoffice is not running, there's a `.lock` file in:
`~/.config/libreoffice/3`

Delete it to unlock your libreoffice settings for access.

A  quick `ps -A | grep soff` should tell you if it's actually running.

Comment: OK. Thanks aking. I found the .lock file and got rid of it. I was able to open documents then but a few seconds after I try to print any document, the whole computer freezes and I have to restart it. Then there's another .lock file. any ideas on what might be causing that or a way to get an error report or something useful? Thanks again for your help

Comment: That last part is a bug and you should report it as such.

Comment: +1 for the process list grep. I assumed LibreOffice's process was named _libre_ - something, and that's why I was unable to find it.

Comment: With libreoffice 4.x the path changes to ~/.config/libreoffice/4/.lock

Comment: This thread is a top google hit, so with apologies to the ubuntu community (I'm an ubuntu user too), if anyone from ``OSX`` gets here, look in ``~/Library/Application Support/libreoffice/4/user`` and ``~/Library/Application Support/libreoffice/4/``

Comment: There is a meta conversation about @PatrickT's comment above, http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15346/ and I am removing the other meta comments before this descends into open warfare.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is the host-name, it should be the same with computer host-name.

I got same error after changing the host-name of my computer
Instead of deleting the file, I was modified the file.

This is my example

```
[Lockdata]
User=teguh
Host=mypc020120001.mydomain <--- it was localhost.localdomain
Stamp=6277AA770908EE6C6E5BAB31537BA8BC
Time=Tue Jul  3 08:09:18 2012
IPCServer=true
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer assumed some knowledge on the part of the user.  This one adds some elaboration.

When an instance of LibreOffice is running a hidden file is set.  This hidden file is called ".lock", the "." indicates it is normally hidden from view.

When you open a terminal window it will normally start in your home directory and will only show you files that have not been set to be hidden.  The home directory is the directory you "own" and normally operate within unless, of course, you assume the persona of the administrator or another user.  So if you type cd .config/libreoffice/3 it will take you to a directory folder, described by "~/.config/libreoffice/3"; the "~" indicating to the operating system you are referencing this command from the point of your home directory.

When you arrive in the folder "3" you will not be able to see the ".lock" file by typing a simple "ls" because, just like the ".config" folder, the ".lock" file is hidden from view.  To see it, type "ls -al".  This will reveal any hidden files in the listing.

To remove this file, once in the "3" folder, you type "rm .lock".  After that you might like to type ls -al just to be sure the ".lock" file is no longer present.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Fedora 24 with LibreOffice 5.1.
I had the same post, asking me to end the process on host such and such.

I clicked yes on the prompt, this led me to the document recovery.
I dicarded the recovery and LibreOffice worked again.

I hope that solves the problem for good.

Answer (score 0):

this paragraph below help me much (I quoted from  ):

> When you open a terminal window it will normally start in your home directory and will only show you files that have not been set to be hidden. The home directory is the directory you "own" and normally operate within unless, of course, you assume the persona of the administrator or another user.
>   So if you type `cd .config/libreoffice/3` it will take you to a directory folder, described by `~/.config/libreoffice/3`; the `~` indicating to the operating system you are referencing this command from the point of your home directory.
>
> When you arrive in the folder `3` you will not be able to see the `.lock` file by typing a simple `ls` because, just like the `.config` folder, the `.lock` file is hidden from view.
>
> To see it, type `ls -al`. This will reveal any hidden files in the listing.

Comment: Could you add from where you got the paragraph?